# How do I move the HTTPERR directory out of my C: Drive

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6

I've got an IIS server that is running a bit low on diskspace on the C: drive; I've moved the W3SVC logs from c:\windows\system32\LogFiles to another drive, but there is also a big HTTPERR folder there that I'd like to move somewhere else.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft have details [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820729) but the summary is:

Go into the registry and amend `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters`
Create a String called `ErrorLoggingDir` and point that somewhere else.  Don't include the `HTTPERR` path, as the HTTP service will create an `HTTPERR` subdirectory anyway.

Then you restart the HTTP service (net stop HTTP, net start HTTP) and then start any dependent services - eg W3SVC.  The HTTP service (http.sys) does not appear in the services MMC, so you have to use a command line to start/stop it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some powershell code that will add the registry key:

`$myRegKeyBase = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\HTTP\Parameters"
    $myRegKeyName = "ErrorLoggingDir"
    $myRegKeyVal  = "D:\inetpub\logs"
    # Create Key property if it doesn't already exist
    $myRC = New-ItemProperty $myRegKeyBase -Name $myRegKeyName -Value $myRegKeyVal -PropertyType String -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    # Update Key property to $iisLogFileDir if it already exists
    Set-ItemProperty $myRegKeyBase -Name $myRegKeyName -Value $myRegKeyVal -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $myProperties = Get-ItemProperty $myRegKeyBase -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Write-Host "regKeyPath: $($myRegKeyBase) regKeyName: $($myRegKeyName) value: $($myProperties.$myRegKeyName)"`